# Does Google crawl content loaded through jQuery's load function?

Tags: jquery, seo

If I have a `test1.html` file containing some info and `test2.html`, when I use

```
.load("test1.html")
```

Will search engines read the content loaded from `test1.html`?

Comment: This is not just bad grammar, this is a messy, improperly written question. -1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Google crawl AJAX content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434445/does-google-crawl-ajax-content)

Comment: sure it is, all he needs to know if ajax is search engine friendly, the answer is yes and no if you use the `<a>` tag to get the link then yes google will follow links and does not wait for a click action of a user. it simply reads the source code and tries to make sense of it all

Comment: deffinately not a dup.  this is a valid question.

Answer (score 2):

You should include an A tag to this page within the body of the page, which Google will follow and index. Then you could hide, or replace this A tag if javascript is present and use your jquery loading approach.