# How Google determine website load time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, seo

So, Google declared that it will use a website loading time as a factor in its ranking algorithm.

Now, I'm building a website with lots of scripts and content that is loaded dynamically. 
Initial scripts run after DOM load, using JQUERY .ready function.
Further scripts run later, when 'onload' occurs, i.e. after 'static' content was rendered (images).
After that, the script dynamically fetch other images, one by one, using subsequent AJAX calls.

My question is not about how much CONTENT Google bots will read or won't read. there are many questions about this matter.

My question is, do you know, or can you suggest, how Google bots will determine the 'LOADING TIME' of such a dynamic website? what is the mechanism for that? if rumors are right and no javascript is executed by the bots, can I assume that the loading time is simply when 'onload' occurs?

Thank you :)

Comment: Excellent question.  Like if you land in a chatroom and people are chatting, the "loading time" is essentially infinite.  Maybe if there is a delay of X seconds after the page loads, would that be enough to give Google the hint the page has finished loading and everything after X seconds is interactive content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my experience  [that is: if  i 'grep googlebot' in my access.log] google usually crawls only html, not js or other things; in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434445/does-google-crawl-ajax-content) you can have some hints about ajax loaded content, but if you're interested in site speed value inside WMT, think about html generation speed, nor css/js assets or whatsoever
EDIT: for details about **who** and **when** crawls your page for index inclusion read [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182072)

Comment: OK but Pingdom counts Javascript generated content toward the "loading time" total. Which is actually why I'm concerned about this. If a Pingdom bot can do it, I would assume Google either has similar technology or plans to roll it out eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this isn't completely true anymore.
Whilst the main indexers (to my knowledge don't index the JS) there are Google bots absolutely **DO** use javascript. For instance the bot which takes screenshots for the preview feature regularly shows parts of sites which require javascript to display.

One thing you can be sure of though is that if they have said that page load speed is a factor, and JS is not being indexed... they won't be using javascript's onload or any jQuery abstraction of this event... it would simply be a question of the http response time and the speed at which your server can transfer the html portion of this.

Comment: wrong. Google takes a snapshot of your site for web preview purposes; you can get those access searching for "(KHTML, like Gecko; Google Web Preview)" in your log files, and this happens for a limited set of pages [those that are selected in search results for preview]. the full index is made of pages indexed as Googlebot, and no other resource that straight HTML is downloaded by the crawler

Comment: are you suggesting that the web preview is not done by a 'bot'?

Comment: it's, of course, a bot but it's not the same used for the index. so the ranking is not affected by the speed of the preview