# Can search engines follow dynamically inserted links/content?

Tags: javascript, html, seo

This one might be close to the question asked here but sightly different

[Are search engines going to see my dynamically created content in Bootstrap tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31637880/are-search-engines-going-to-see-my-dynamically-created-content-in-bootstrap-tabs)

At a high level, these are three types of ways I could think of adding content/links to page
1. Initial:- links/content available in downloaded html markup which server sends to client.
2. OnLoad:- As part of onload, content can be fetched from a rest service and included in dom.
3. On user action:- When user click on a tab content/links will be fetched from server.

From above thread, these cases are confirmed

1. In case 1(Initial), Content will be indexed by googlebot but hidden content will get less weightage.
2. In case 3(on user action) it was clearly answered that googlebot will not know about content/links which are lazily loaded on click and hence can't follow or index links/content.

Questions on hidden links/content:

1. In case 1(Initial), if I have links which are hidden(display:none), Can googlebot still follow those links and index them?
2. In case 2(on Load), will it follow both **hidden and visible** links and index them?
3. In case 2(on load), can I assume that googlebot indexes the hidden content?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes. 3. Yes. Google bot only doesn't follow links that have `rel="nofollow"`. When content is hidden it's impossible to tell if that's a UX quirk (for instance you're using tabs or have a fold-in menu) or if it's an attempt to trick the Google crawler. This article might also help you: http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157 I think it's safe to assume Google will try their best to index your site. What doesn't work today might work tomorrow.

Comment: Googlebot won't index "dynamically generated content" but it will index "hidden"(with css) content just fine. In all your cases, you have hidden content and not dynamically generated content so it will index it just fine.

Comment: Read the top of the [tag:seo] tag.